# How to change windows.confirm callBack event

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, confirm

I want to change to the default browser confirm box.

However, I couldn't do this. Can you guide me?

```
window.confirm = function (message, title, callback, parameter) {    
    var intSonuc = zekiConfirm($(document).attr('title'), message, callback, parameter);

    return intSonuc;
};

function zekiConfirm(strBaslik, strMesaj, callback, parameter) {
    $('body').append('<div class="divAlertBack"></div><div class="divAlertCerceve"><div class="divAlertCerceveIc"><span>' + strBaslik + '</span><p>' + strMesaj + '</p><input id="btnTamam" type="submit" value="Tamam"></input><input id="btnIptal" type="submit" value="İptal"></input></div></div>');

    $('.divAlertBack').fadeIn(300);
    $('.divAlertCerceve').fadeIn(300);

    $('.divAlertCerceve #btnTamam').click(function () {
        zekiAlertConfirmClose();

        return callback;
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: When I click button, I never checked value that is "return true". Because of this, btnDelete did not start deleting event. Callback is not working.

Comment: your `intSonuc` value will be undefined. because you are not returning anything in `zekiConfirm`.

Comment: When button clicked, how am I send "return true" send to window.confirm?